# При запуске консоль выдает, что прекращена работа программы

Tags: c, алгоритм, функции

```
int perfect(long n)
{
    int a[50],i,ind=0,suma=0;
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if (n%i==0)
        {
            a[ind]=i;
            ind++;
        }
    }
    ind--;
    for (i=ind;i>=0;i--)
    {
        suma=suma + a[i];
    }
    if (suma==n*2) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Функция должна определять является ли число совершенным, но при запуске консоль выдает, что прекращена работа программы.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе точный текст ошибки, которую вы получаете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уже в самом начале функции имеется деление на 0.

```
for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
     ^^^^^
{
    if (n%i==0)
       ^^^^
    {
```

Из стандарта C (6.5.5 Multiplicative operators)

> 5 The result of the / operator is the quotient from the division of
>   the ﬁrst operand by the second; the result of the % operator is the
>   remainder. **In both operations, if the value of the second operand is
>   zero, the behavior is undeﬁned**

Вот как функция может быть написана

```
#include <stdio.h>

int perfect(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long sum = n != 1;

    for (unsigned long i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) sum += i;
    }

    return sum == n;
}

int main( void )
{
    for (unsigned long i = 1; i < 500; i++)
    {
        if (perfect(i) ) printf("%lu ", i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
6 28 496
```

Comment: Кстати интересно, по какой причине у топикстартера не выводится текст ошибки/исключения.

Comment: @Kromster Со слов автора выдается какое-то сообщение, говорящее, что работа программы прекращена.

Comment: Я уже заметил , что поставил деление на 0

Comment: @MrShef Смотрите также в моем ответе, как функция может быть реализована.

Answer (score 1):

Даже если вы работаете перебором, нет смысла перебирать **всё**.
Посмотрите на этот вариант:

```
int perfect(long n)
{
    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n%i == 0)
        {
            sum += i + n/i;
        }
    }
    return (sum == n);
}
```